# How to directly upload to specified folder on web Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I've make a folder in my storage like this picture

[image]

I've try to add my folder name in my **storageBucket** URL like this

[image]

And showing error **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at...(Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)**.
What's the correct storageBucket URL for this case ?
Or is there any other option ?

Here's my complete code :

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: " ",
    authDomain: " ",
    projectId: " ",
    storageBucket: " ",
    messagingSenderId: " ",
    appId: " ",
    measurementId: " "

};



   // Initialize Firebase
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   console.log(firebase);

   function uploadImage() {
      const ref = firebase.storage().ref();
      const file = document.querySelector("#foto").files[0];
      const name = +new Date() + "-" + file.name;
      const metadata = {
         contentType: file.type
      };
      const task = ref.child(name).put(file, metadata);task
      .then(snapshot => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL())
      .then(url => {
      console.log(url);
      alert('SUKSES !');

      urlFoto.value=url;
   })
   .catch(console.error);
   }
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Also: none of the code in your question uses the Firestore API for Cloud Storage yet, so it seems unlikely this will trigger the error you have. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My Apologize sir...Yeah I've already got a solution, thnks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Add the folder name inside `.ref();`

```
function uploadImage() {
      const ref = firebase.storage().ref('folder-name');
      const file = document.querySelector("#foto").files[0];
      const name = +new Date() + "-" + file.name;
      const metadata = {
         contentType: file.type
      };
```